# A Girl Who is a Magnicus (Summons Spirits and Absorbs Them Into Own Body)

Tags: story-identification

I've got this story in my head about a girl and spirit-summoning but I'm not sure whether it's from a book or from a movie. It has bothered me last night but I can't seem to remember. I can remember the faces of the characters (so it's probably a movie or a tv series [?]), though and a few scenes and lines. The details are as follows.

**Definition of Term(s)**

1. Magnicus - A person who can summon spirits and sort of like absorb them into his/her own body, either to destroy them, make use of their abilities or extract information from them (not sure).

**Character Identification**

-There's this 'protagonist' girl who has got one dead eye (right). The dead eye looks like it's got cataract and it moves rapidly and is shaky (like during REM). Through it, the girl can see spirits/ghosts/anything eldritch. Her eyes are slightly 'exotropic'. She is a Magnicus. The girl is bald and has two subdermal implants within her forehead which looked like doughnuts. She's got tattoos on her neck, and her arms. She's got piercings on her right eyebrow and another below her lower lip. Despite how she looks, she is actually pretty, soft-spoken and kind-hearted. She's got a father.

-The girl's father also has subdermal implants similar to her and is also bald. He's also got tattoos on his neck, arms, back and chest. He has more facial piercings than her daughter. He knows of his daughter's abilities and is very supportive of her.

-Then there's a 'protagonist' guy who meets the girl and gets attracted to her. He works for an organization dealing with the supernatural and trains Magnici [?] (not sure of the plural form). He is like a scientist or a tech-expert creates devices to aid the organization in dealing with the supernatural. He's got limp, messy rustic brunette hair and he's got thin beard.

**Scenes I Remember**

The guy meets the girl and gets attracted to her. He learns of her abilities but I don't know how. He then invites the girl to the organization he works for so she could have proper training as a Magnicus. The girl is hesitant so she asks her father. The father agrees. While they were walking on a busy side-walk, the girl, as usual, would see spirits. When they neared the organization's building, the girl pauses and says "Wait. Stop!" upon seeing the great flux of spirits into and out of the building.

They enter the building. As they take a tour, they see a training Magnicus (one of the best). He's wearing a basketball jersey (like that of the Chicago Bulls) and khaki pants. Both looks baggy on him since he is really thin. He was bare-footed. There's a floating thing which looks like an inverted fish bowl (to about 120 degrees) beside him. It looks ethereal. I think he uses it to summon the spirits (like a portal). In the lab, there's a device that makes spirits unseen to normal human eye seen. Thus, they saw the long chain of ghosts/spirits the training Magnicus has summoned and absorbed into his body. At first, he seemed successful and exclaimed "I did it! I did it!" But, suddenly, his body started shaking and contorting. Apparently, he had summoned too many and had summoned a number of dangerous and powerful spirits. He was sucked into the floating bowl from head to chest. The 'protagonist' guy tried to help him by pulling him out. After so much struggling, the Magnicus' body was out of the bowl and his body has calmed down. But he did not. He cried "Minerva! Minerva! Oh, Minerva! Please don't give me a clock for a bride! (and at this point, strange enough, he was holding an alarm clock in his hands) Guess I'll just have to go for my eyes." He, then, gouged his eyes out with his bare hands.

That's all I could remember. I can't give you a date nor a year. But I can give you a time. It was about 3am last night. It came to me in a dream. That was why I could remember the faces and the settings. It was the most vivid dream I have ever had. If this story seems familiar to you, please do tell me. When I woke up, I was so perturbed with the last scene that I felt like throwing up. Thank you!

Comment: *Magnicus*, by Phebe S, published in the mid-2010s. Currently missing from ISFDB for some reason.

Comment: Seriously… we can hardly explain your dream. Maybe there are elements that were inspired from SF works, but you'll have to break it down into something that is genuinely from one book or movie and not from your imagination.